# Reverse engineering in one package

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect

I have a java project with many packages and I am trying to do a reverse engineering with EA but I couldn't find a way to create one class diagram.

Ver 7.0.813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one. You can either have EA create no diagrams at all, or one diagram per package.

You can't make it create a single diagram with everything in it, nor can you select to create diagrams only for some specific packages (although that can be achieved by doing multiple separate source imports).